# How to find the location for background process?

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application.In that i want to find out the x,y,z axis values in the background process.For this first i find the device location.After find the device location i will try to get the x,y,z axis values.So please tell me how to find out the location in the background.

Comment: x,y,z relative to what? Are you converting from latitude/longitude/altitide to 3D Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: first please tell me,how to find the device location in the background

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If with x,y,z axis values you are referring to the device orientation, then you need to use the UIAccelerometer class and it's protocol.

[UIAccelerometer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html)

Comment: But,this class and it's delegate is only working when the applicationis in normal mode not in background

Comment: But,that class and delegate method are working when the application is in normal mode.so how to find out device location first and x,y,z values next.

Comment: I see, when you meant background I thought you didn't want it blocking your main thread. In that case, I don't think it's possible, specially since only certain apps are allowed to keep executing instructions while on the background.

Comment: Sir,please tell me the reason.Because my Manager ask that one also

Comment: Apple doesn't want apps to drain the battery and slow the device when they are not being explicitly used by the user. Instead you should show the user a warning telling him that the app will not be able to function if he exits it or locks his device.

Comment: Iam using location service for finding the latitude and longitude values.ANd based on this if locatoion changes, wake up my application.In this service based on which one we find the location.BAsed on cell towers or based on satellite or anything else

Answer (score 0):

If you want location updates in the background, just set [UIBackgroundModes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) in Info.plist. Something like this should work:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
  <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Note that keeping the GPS on all the time reduces battery life significantly (~6h?). You can set desiredAccuracy to something larger if you're happy with less frequent updates.